# Test iAds showing up in Live iPhone application?

Tags: iphone

I have a version 1.0.1 that is live right now.
I submitted version 1.1.1 which is currently for waiting for review.
I have reset the devices that had test 1.1.1 versions and downloaded 1.0.1 from the AppStore from the device.  But, test iAds are showing up on live app.  Has anyone encountered this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try going into "Settings"->"General"->"Profiles" and delete the developer profile related to your app, and see if that fixes the issue.